# Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'web' in IE browser using AngularJs 4

Tags: angularjs, browser, routes, angular-ui-router, internet-explorer-11

I have developed application using angular4. I am able load the Application and browse all pages in chrome, mozila and safari browser except IE browser. I have latest internet explorer 11 version. I am not getting why application working in IE, I searched couple of articles mentioned to change in route I have done it but still I am not able load the pages. Can anybody tel me how resolve this issue. Application deployed in tomcat server. Please find the screenshot for the more reference. Great appreciate.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './home/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AdminusersComponent } from './home/dashboard/adminusers/adminusers.component';
import { CreatenewclaimComponent } from './home/dashboard/createnewclaim/createnewclaim.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'Createnewclaim', component: CreatenewclaimComponent },
            { path: 'adminUsers', component: AdminusersComponent }
        ]
    },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

IE Browser

[image]

tomcat server deployed location.

[image]

Working in the chrome browser, safari, mizilla

[image]

Comment: Try following: replace ip with localhost, and try exactly the same url for IE which you tried for Chrome. And share your routing module.

Comment: @slesh If I put local host it works. but not working with IP.

Comment: @slesh, Aleardy I have shared routing module above, why its not wrking from the server ip. It works in all other browser but not in IE

Comment: Have you tried the same url as for Chrome? Do you have localhost and server? Share console network tab for chrome and IE.

Comment: @slesh yes I have tried both local and server IP in the chrome browser. Both URL working fine in the chrome without any issue. Already I have shared both browser consloe tabs as above screen shot. Please you can have a look.

Comment: I need network tab, not the console. I'd like to look at queries, maybe browser adds some specific headers that result to the problem.